# How to convert a list into a string

Tags: python, sql, django, string

When I do a database query I am returning a result of `[('2c1bfbcc99ba4bc6858110a8fee2dc7c',)]` which contains the string I need. However, I need to remove the brackets, parentheses, and the comma. The above value is stored in a variable called `result`

I have tried `str(result)` but that just returns `"[('2c1bfbcc99ba4bc6858110a8fee2dc7c',)]"` which does not help at ALL.

I am looking for a way to parse out the brackets, parentheses, and the comma using just a few lines of python. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a string wrapped in a tuple in a list. You can obtain this with `result[0][0]`, but the question is more why this happened.

Comment: If you see a result like this and think about what needs to be done in terms of "removing punctuation", then you should probably take a step back and review some language fundamentals.

Comment: @AustinHallett: is there a reason why you do not use the Django ORM?

Comment: Anyway, the result is like this because you are fetching rows from a database with `.fetchall`; the outer list is needed because *there could be more than one row in the result* for a DB query in general, and the inner tuple is because *there could be more than one column*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not sure what the ORM is. I am new to Django this is my first project.

Comment: @AustinHallett: I think you should really follow the Django tutorial. This explains how to make models, make ORM queries, etc. By making raw queries, Django will not be that helpful, especially since nearly all (`ModelForm`s, Class-based views, etc.) are focussing on models and making `QuerySet`s for these models.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Okay that makes perfect sense. 
Here is my code:
``` 
db_query="SELECT product_id FROM product_table WHERE product_name LIKE 'generic product name' "

    #execute the SQL statement
    cursor.execute(db_query)

    #assign result to variable
    result=cursor.fetchall()
```
How could I pull the one result? I only every expect one result based on the criteria of the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

This is a string wrapped in a tuple in a list. You can obtain this with `result[0][0]`. This will however only work if these are two subscriptable collections that each have at least one element. Furthermore if the tuple for example has multiple elements, then we here only pick the first one, which is not per se the correct choice.

The question is more *why* this happened. If a function always returns a single string, it might not be a good idea to wrap it in collections.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query is:

```
result = [('2c1bfbcc99ba4bc6858110a8fee2dc7c',)]
```

You can get the string using:

```
result_str = result[0][0]
```

If you have multiple results, you can joing them using:

```
result = [('1', '2', '3',)]
result_str = ''.join(result[0])
>>> '123'
```

Or:

```
result = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
result_str = ''.join([i[0] for i in result])
>>> '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean is like↓

```py
x = [('2c1bfbcc99ba4bc6858110a8fee2dc7c',)]
print(x[0][0])
```

result

```
2c1bfbcc99ba4bc6858110a8fee2dc7c
```